# Brick element generalisation

Tags: abaqus

I am working on input file creation using Matlab which can be opened in Abaqus.  I habe written a code for shell elements which is as below

```matlab
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', '*Shell Section, elset=LAYUPX-1, composite, orientation=Ori-1, layup=LAYUPX');
```

However now I am working on eight node quadratic elements and I always get an error in Abaqus saying:

> Unknown keyword, The keyword may be misspelled, obsolete, or invalid.

Can anyone let me know which is the correct keyword which I can use instead of "Shell Section" so avoid this error?

Comment: What element type are you using specifically?  Only certain element types can use the `composite` keyword.

Comment: I am using SC8R ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Solid Section and it should solve your problem